# Azure IoT Hub RegistryManager update many twins - only if properties exist

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-iot-hub

How can I make sure that `RegistryManager.UpdateTwins2Async()` only updates properties to the device twins and never adds them if they don't exist? To explain...

I'm developing an Azure IoT web application in .NET Core 3.1. I need to update multiple device device twins in the IoT Hub with a patch. So far, I'm doing this

`var updateTask = await mRegistryManager.UpdateTwins2Async(finalTwinList);`

But now we have a new version of IoT devices that contain extra properties and therefore I only want to update properties in devices that HAVE those properties (i.e. only the devices with the new version).

I know that the `UpdateTwins2Async()` method changes the properties if they are found in a device but I'm pretty sure that it ADDS them if they don't exist. It would be very bad if those new properties were added to the older devices.

So how can I make sure that `UpdateTwins2Async()` only updates properties and never adds them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer, but it might not fit your solution. If you want to make sure that you're only doing this for the correct devices, you could first retrieve them using a query and then check your finalTwinList again.

```
var list = new List<Twin>();
var sql = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE is_defined(properties.desired.yourtaghere)";
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery(sql, 100);
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
    foreach (var twin in page)
    {
        list.Add(twin);
    }
}

// now check your finalTwinList, any device ID that's not also in your newly created list can go!
```

If you're only updated a handful of devices at a time and have a few thousand devices in your hub, that query is overkill. You could change it to be more specific:

```
SELECT * FROM devices
  WHERE deviceId IN ['entries', 'from', 'your', 'list']
  AND is_defined(properties.desired.yourtaghere)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess this will work. This method will only be updating a subset of the devices, so I'll know the device id list to put in ```where deviceId IN```. But the client will sent in a string list of property names and value pairs to be changed for all those devices and some devices will perhaps not have some of these properties. So I guess that for all the new properties, I will have to add a ```is_defined()``` function to the query.

Comment: Glad it fits your use case, if you could mark the answer as accepted that will help others find it too!

Comment: One question - Is it possible to to let the UpdateTwins() method (or some related one) only change properties that exist? And the properties that don't exists, they won't be added to the device twin? I.e. so that nothing gets added, only updated.

Comment: The SDK offers no built-in method to do that as far as I can tell. It would make a nice [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks) perhaps?